# Why can't I hook the bind method to this class?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to refresh the browser when the user clicks a close button (which is labeled 
.ps-toolbar-close), but I get zilch. Does it matter there's no actual HTML for this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ps-toolbar-close").bind("click", function() {
        location.reload();
    });
   });
```

This is the backstory; I am using a plugin called scrollUp and it has this great 'destroy' method which kills it; So basically I want to restart it but only after the user hits a certain button.

I figure refreshing/reloading the browser is a neat way to restart the plugin. 
I am doing this because there's ***another*** plugin that scrollUp is not playing nice with...the other plugin is photoswipe...

Any insight would be appreciated, as this is driving me to drink (beyond my normal intake).
j/k...

My html;

:)

```
<ul class="galleryContainer gallery">

                <li>
                    <a href="images/galleryImages/full/001.jpg" rel="external">
                        <img src="images/galleryImages/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" class="destroy"> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="images/galleryImages/full/002.jpg" rel="external">
                        <img src="images/galleryImages/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" class="destroy">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="images/galleryImages/full/003.jpg" rel="external">
                        <img src="images/galleryImages/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" class="destroy">
                    </a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show the html :) May be using jsfiddle ..

Comment: This is what i have so far...
http://aortiz.info/mirophotography/wedding_page.html

Comment: Where is `.ps-toolbar-close` element in your page that is bound to `click` event.

Comment: .ps-toolbar-close is being called only in css. This is the way 'photoswipe' was created, that's the other plugin which is not playing so nicely with scrollUp!

Comment: Don't you have any element in the `HTML` with class `.ps-toolbar-close` ? If, not then how do you click on `non-existent` button/element ?

Comment: I tired it but it didn't work. Thanks though... Originally I had wondered that myself, (not having a actual element in the HTML) but i realized 'photoswipe' has a few classes which don't have actual html. I figured they were using javaScript/Jquery to add them dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

does the element have "ps-toolbar-close" as a class on the element?  If it's the id use "#ps-toolbar-close"

You need to add the class to the element you'd like the click to attach to

`<div class="ps-toolbar-close"> This is where your click would be attached </div>`

Comment: So if I go to the CSS rule and add #ps-toolbar-close to the selector?